# CASE-WHEN within function POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function to insert some values into a table, but before inserting I want to check if e-mail address it's right. If not, break the function and returns an error. Case true, go on.

```
case when _email ~ '^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$' = true 
then raise exception 'Incorrect email'
```

_email is the parameter of funcion.
But it's not working. Should I use "IF" or other conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` works, but `IF` seems more appropriate.
You have some pointless noise in the expression and I think you got the logic backwards: 'Incorrect email' should be triggered if `_email` does *not* match the pattern:

```
IF _email ~ '^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$'  -- drop the pointless "= true"
THEN  -- do nothing - I inverted the logic
ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION 'Incorrect email';
END IF;
```

The new [`ASSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSERT) (Postgres 9.5+) would also work, but that's really meant for debugging:

```
ASSERT _email ~ '^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$', 'Incorrect email';
```

Comment: Worked great. I'm using this way in my function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the case inside plpgsql. Obviously what you are trying to do can be done through if statement as well...

```
 case when _email ~ '^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+(\.[^@\s]+)+$' = true then
           raise exception 'Incorrect email';
      else
           --proceed with insert
  end case;
```